# How to design a Responsive Web with Ad Placements using HTML5 and CSS3?

Tags: responsive-design

I am trying to design a Website with Ad placements(to house Google Adsense embedded HTML) that would show meaningfully in full size screens and also on mobile devices. In the former case (full size), the Ads will show as floats to the right on arbitrary text. In the latter case, the Ads will show at the bottom of the text. The text would typically be some dynamic content on the website.

My attempt to implement this is to have these Ad placement (2 Ads) enclosed by divs above and below the arbitrary text.

```
<div class="parent1">
   <div class="ad1">Ad 1 </div>
   <div class="ad2">Ad 2 </div>
</div>

<p> ......Text </p>
<div class="parent2">
   <div class="ad1">Ad 1 </div>
   <div class="ad2">Ad 2 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS3's Media Query function is utilized to hide and unhide Ad placements at the the screen width cutover from Mobile to regular screen size. A simplified width: 414px is used as the cutoff for a Mobile Phone to full screen size)

```
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 414px){

.asideleft {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.parent1 {
    display:none;
}
.parent2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    display:block;
    clear: none;
}
}
```

I am a beginner in HTML and CSS. My implementation is inelegant and probably not the correct way to do this but I did try to keep it as simple as possible. Appreciate if any suggestions on better ways.

Thanks

Sean

```css
h1 {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 2.5%;
 width: 30%;
 float: left;
 color: #F3ECED;
}
nav {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 background-color: #1D0606;
 color: #E9D4D5;
 float: none;
}

h2 {
 color: #F3EBEB;
 float: right;
}
p {
 color: #F4EDED;
 clear: left;
}
footer {
 font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 float: left;
}
header {
 text-align: center;
}
img {
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
}


body {
 font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 background-image: url(images/header_bg.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}


.asideleft {
}

.asideleft_more {
 margin-left: 2.5%; 
}

.parent1{
 width: 300px;
 height: 500px;
 float: right;
 clear: none;
}

.parent2 {
 display: none;
}

.ad1{
    width:300px;
 height:250px;
    background:blue;
}

.ad2{
    width:300px;
 height:250px;
    background:green;
}


@media (min-width: 414px){

}

@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 414px){
 
.asideleft {
 margin-right: 0px;
}
.parent1 {
 display:none;
}
.parent2 {
 width: 300px;
 height: 500px;
 float: left;
 display:block;
 clear: none;
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<header><img src="images/foo.png" width="80" height="80" alt=""/>
<nav>This is a Header</nav>
</header>

<aside class="asideleft">

<div class="parent1">
    <div class="ad1">Ad 1 </div>
    <div class="ad2">Ad 2 </div>
</div>
<aside class="asideleft_more">
  <h1 class="header_1">Sub Header</h1>
  <p>Altera molestiae eu quo. No duo porro postulant gubergren, veritus vocibus vituperata vis ut. Option voluptua nam no, vix malis iuvaret principes ut, ex dicunt aliquam vix. Noluisse senserit efficiendi ea nec, movet equidem consectetuer cum no. Pro id periculis mnesarchum interesset, munere legimus te eum. Libris quidam reprimique eum et. Illum quidam repudiandae no nam, sit no libris euismod. Dicta nostro has ea. Probatus referrentur instructior id eum.
Vel unum copiosae aliquando ne. Cu qui ignota mandamus deterruisset, an eum officiis conceptam. Vim et minim equidem, essent voluptaria assueverit vel et. Noster equidem sit ei, exerci labitur fabellas ut has. Mel modus electram ut, denique mediocrem qualisque eos id. Tamquam efficiantur cu vis, eu reque philosophia vix, an diam case soleat his.           
</p>
</aside>
<div class="parent2">
    <div class="ad1">Ad 1' </div>
    <div class="ad2">Ad 2' </div>
</div>
</aside>

<footer>This is a footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1 {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 2.5%;
 width: 30%;
 float: left;
 color: #F3ECED;
}
nav {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 background-color: #1D0606;
 color: #E9D4D5;
 float: none;
}

h2 {
 color: #F3EBEB;
 float: right;
}
p {
 color: #F4EDED;
 clear: left;
}
footer {
 font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 float: left;
}
header {
 text-align: center;
}
img {
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
}


body {
 font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 background-image: url(images/header_bg.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}


.asideleft {
}

.asideleft_more {
 margin-left: 2.5%; 
}

.parent1{
 /*width: 300px;
 height: 500px;
 float: right;
 clear: none;*/
 width: 40%;
 height: auto;
 clear: none;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
}

.parent2 {
 display: none;
}

.ad1{
    width:300px;
 height:250px;
    background:blue;
}

.ad2{
    width:300px;
 height:250px;
    background:green;
}


@media (min-width: 414px){

}

@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 414px){
 
.asideleft {
 margin-right: 0px;
}
.parent1 {
 display:none;
}
.parent2 {
 width: 300px;
 height: 500px;
 float: left;
 display:block;
 clear: none;
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<header><img src="images/foo.png" width="80" height="80" alt=""/>
<nav>This is a Header</nav>
</header>

<aside class="asideleft">

<div class="parent1">
    <div class="ad1">Ad 1 </div>
    <div class="ad2">Ad 2 </div>
</div>
<aside class="asideleft_more">
  <h1 class="header_1">Sub Header</h1>
  <p>Altera molestiae eu quo. No duo porro postulant gubergren, veritus vocibus vituperata vis ut. Option voluptua nam no, vix malis iuvaret principes ut, ex dicunt aliquam vix. Noluisse senserit efficiendi ea nec, movet equidem consectetuer cum no. Pro id periculis mnesarchum interesset, munere legimus te eum. Libris quidam reprimique eum et. Illum quidam repudiandae no nam, sit no libris euismod. Dicta nostro has ea. Probatus referrentur instructior id eum.
Vel unum copiosae aliquando ne. Cu qui ignota mandamus deterruisset, an eum officiis conceptam. Vim et minim equidem, essent voluptaria assueverit vel et. Noster equidem sit ei, exerci labitur fabellas ut has. Mel modus electram ut, denique mediocrem qualisque eos id. Tamquam efficiantur cu vis, eu reque philosophia vix, an diam case soleat his.           
</p>
</aside>
<div class="parent2">
    <div class="ad1">Ad 1' </div>
    <div class="ad2">Ad 2' </div>
</div>
</aside>

<footer>This is a footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
h1 {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 2.5%;
 width: 30%;
 float: left;
 color: #F3ECED;
}
nav {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 background-color: #1D0606;
 color: #E9D4D5;
 float: none;
}

h2 {
 color: #F3EBEB;
 float: right;
}
p {
 color: #F4EDED;
 clear: left;
}
footer {
 font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 float: left;
}
header {
 text-align: center;
}
img {
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
}


body {
 font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 background-image: url(images/header_bg.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}


.asideleft {
}

.asideleft_more {
 margin-left: 2.5%; 
}

.parent1{
 width: 300px;
 height: 500px;
 float: right;
 clear: none;
}

.parent2 {
 display: none;
}

.ad1{
    width:300px;
 height:250px;
    background:blue;
}

.ad2{
    width:300px;
 height:250px;
    background:green;
}


@media (min-width: 414px){

}

@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 414px){
 
.asideleft {
 margin-right: 0px;
}
.parent1 {
 display:none;
}
.parent2 {
 width: 300px;
 height: 500px;
 float: left;
 display:block;
 clear: none;
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<header><img src="images/foo.png" width="80" height="80" alt=""/>
<nav>This is a Header</nav>
</header>

<aside class="asideleft">

<div class="parent1">
    <div class="ad1">Ad 1 </div>
    <div class="ad2">Ad 2 </div>
</div>
<aside class="asideleft_more">
  <h1 class="header_1">Sub Header</h1>
  <p>Altera molestiae eu quo. No duo porro postulant gubergren, veritus vocibus vituperata vis ut. Option voluptua nam no, vix malis iuvaret principes ut, ex dicunt aliquam vix. Noluisse senserit efficiendi ea nec, movet equidem consectetuer cum no. Pro id periculis mnesarchum interesset, munere legimus te eum. Libris quidam reprimique eum et. Illum quidam repudiandae no nam, sit no libris euismod. Dicta nostro has ea. Probatus referrentur instructior id eum.
Vel unum copiosae aliquando ne. Cu qui ignota mandamus deterruisset, an eum officiis conceptam. Vim et minim equidem, essent voluptaria assueverit vel et. Noster equidem sit ei, exerci labitur fabellas ut has. Mel modus electram ut, denique mediocrem qualisque eos id. Tamquam efficiantur cu vis, eu reque philosophia vix, an diam case soleat his.           
</p>
</aside>
<div class="parent2">
    <div class="ad1">Ad 1' </div>
    <div class="ad2">Ad 2' </div>
</div>
</aside>

<footer>This is a footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I have just modified this class, please check the above code snippet and let me know whether it is helpful or not :) 
Cheers,
G...
.parent1{
 /*width: 300px;
 height: 500px;
 float: right;
 clear: none;*/
 width: 40%;
 height: auto;
 clear: none;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
}

Comment: No sure how this would help. Try the script I wrote works - perhaps I used the word "attempt" too vaguely. I am saying that what I did works but is there a better way.

Comment: Hmm .. I found supporting answer here :http://bloggingyourpassion.com/what-is-google-adsense-how-does-it-work/   That is, yes, hiding Ad placements using HTML5 and CSS3 is one way. The other is using Javascript but my goal was do it in using HTML5 and CSS3 only for simplicity. So there you have it :-)